# How do I integrate Next.js template with my existing Django Application?

Tags: python, django, next.js

I have been working on my Django app. Currently it has a simple HTML hero page for the front end. I have purchased this https://tailwindui.com/templates/salient template from Tailwind. I would like to integrate this into my existing django project. I only intend to use it as a marketing site.

Can someone guide me as to what I need to do?

Cheers